# Exporting outlook contacts

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, contacts, google-contacts, gmail-contacts

So, I have quite a lot of emails in Outlook I'd like to "harvest" contacts (to/from fields) from and add to Google contacts. Note that I'm not talking about the Outlook address book, but Outlook emails scattered in many different folders.

Is there way to do this, preferably automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free [Save Email Addresses from Messages](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesEmailSave) utility to save emails to a text file and then import this file to Google contacts. I recommend this tool because I'm one of the developers.